# Pdfcrowd Error: [26] couldn't open file "data.php"

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have to convert one export file into pdf.For that I am using PDFcrowed
But there one problem occured if I use convertFile and convertURL it's work and convert into pdf If I have pass path of php file.It's give a error.
**invoices.php**

```
<?php
require 'pdfcrowd.php';

try
{   
    // create an API client instance
    $client = new Pdfcrowd("priyankaahire", "b50ca6e682a7194f24bf2081470d074f");

    $pdf = $client->convertFile('data.php');
    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");

    // send the generated PDF 
    echo $pdf;
}
catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
{
    echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why;
}
?>
```

**data.php**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>NO.</th>
        <!-- <th>MAWBNO</th>-->
        <th>HAWBNO</th>
        <th>Consignee Name</th>
        <th>Consignee Address</th>
        <th>Sender Name</th>
        <th>Sender Address</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //connection to mysql
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //server , username , password
    mysql_select_db("shepherddb");

    //query get data
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ship_hawbno,cust_fname,cust_street from shipment,customers
     where shipment.ship_consignee_id=customers.cust_id or shipment.ship_shipper_id=customers.cust_id and shipment.ship_id=2");
    $no = 1;
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$no.'</td>
            <td>'.$data['ship_hawbno'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['cust_fname'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['cust_street'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['cust_fname'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['cust_street'].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: What error do you have exactly? I don't know how php pdfcrowd works, but I suspect that `->convertFile('data.php');` is not a valid request. Try to use HTTP url of your file, not the local filename.

Comment: Can I pass localhost path to the convertFile('http://localhost/shepherdlogistics_v1.0/backend/views/shipment/data.php')

Comment: Pdfcrowd Error: convertFile(): 'http://localhost/shepherdlogistics_v1.0/backend/views/shipment/data.php' not found Possible reasons: 1. The file is missing. 2. You misspelled the file name. 3. You use a relative file path (e.g. 'index.html') but the current working directory is somewhere else than you expect: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\shepherdlogistics_v1.0\backend\views\shipment' Generally, it is safer to use an absolute file path instead of a relative one.

Comment: I got error after passing localhost path

Comment: I correct myself: `->convertFile` works only on local files. You have to pass a valid filepath. Try using the absolute filepath (NO HTTP, i'm sorry). Note that php code will be ignored in conversion.

Comment: Now I have pass this$pdf = $client->convertFile('http://192.168.0.108/shepherdlogistics_v1.0/backend/views/shipment/demo.html');

Comment: File not found error occur and if I will remove full path only pass demo.html could not open error occur

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `->convertFile()` method you have to pass a local HTML filePath. Your error is clear:

> 1. The file is missing.
> 2. You misspelled the file name.
> 3. You use a relative file path (e.g. 'index.html') but the current working
>      directory is somewhere else than you expect: '${cwd}'
>      Generally, it is safer to use an absolute file path instead of a relative one.

In your specific case, the `data.php` is not in the same directory of executing script. Use the **absolute filepath** instead.

---

**Carefully note:**

Using this method, you send the raw php file to *PDFcrowd* (with your php code visible, including eventually sensible data). The conversion process **will ignore** all php code and will convert **only plain HTML** in page.

In other words, if your `test.php` page is like this one:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;">Hello <?php echo 'World'; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your browser you see that:

```
┌─────────────┐
│ Hello World │
└─────────────┘
```

But, after `->convertFile( '/Absolute/Path/to/test.php' )` your converted pdf file will look like this:

```
┌───────┐
│ Hello │
└───────┘
```

If you want convert processed php file, you can try something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents( 'http://localhost/path/to/your/test.php' );
file_put_contents( '/Absolute/Path/To/tempfile.html', $html );
$pdf = $client->convertFile( '/Absolute/Path/To/tempfile.html' );
```

In other words, you have first to retrieve the url, then to save it to a file, then to convert saved file.

As alternative, you can use `->convertURI()` instead of `->convertFile()`:

```
$pdf = $client->convertURI( 'http://www.example.com/path/to/your/test.php' );
```

In this case, you have to replace 'www.example.com' with a valid **hostname** or a **reachable IP** address (So, **NO** localhost, **NO** 192.168.0.108).